# Why does the Microsoft Teams App require "Local Network" permissions to allow calling into meetings?

Tags: iphone, network, permission, ms-teams

I use the MS Teams iOS app for work (at a large US corporation) and one of the (numerous) problems I've found with the app relates to it requiring special "Local Network" permission for calls, especially calling into a meeting.

What does this setting provide to and enable for the app?

What if any risk exists when enabling this permission?

If there's a way to work around this and mitigate any risk associated with the setting that would be helpful to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question to Microsoft as to why they need that permission?  They're the ones who stated they need it.

Comment: No @fsb. I don't trust that vendor and simply use their products when required for business and there's a measured tradeoff. I asked here as it's relating to the Apple platform and permissions system interface that platform provides. That's the context of the question. And is relevant to other apps where this specific information relates.